# Search item in an array of another Javascript file (AngularJS used)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, google-maps, search

I am a newbie in AngularJS. I decided to created a custom map with my markers (that I defined).
So, I created a javascript file with just an array :

```
var myMarkers=[{
   method1='..',
   methode2='..'
 },{
   method1='..',
   methode2='..'
}]
```

Then, I created a app.s file which is an AngularJS directive to create the map

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
directive('myMap', function() {
   var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
       function initMap(){..};   
       function setMarker(map, position, title, content,link){..};
       function returnMarker(){..};
   }
   return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: link
    };
});
```

In my index.html,

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>...</head>
<body>
<div my-map=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine but I would like to add a research function to find a marker and then center the map on this marker.
Something like this :

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search your place" ng-model='search'></input>
<p ng-repeat="marker in myMarkers| filter: search> {{marker.title}}</p>
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are asking for three things: 1) Access an array from another file in your controller. 2) Do filtering/search on markers. 3) How to center map on a marker.

To store your array in another file and access it in your controller do the following:

-- mymarkers.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.constant("myMarkers", [{
   method1='..',
   methode2='..'
 },{
   method1='..',
   methode2='..'
}]);
```

-- app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').controller("myController", ["$scope", "myMarkers", function($scope, myMarkers){
    $scope.markers= myMarkers; 
    $scope.searchMarkers = function(){
// loop through your markers array and compare with the entered value in text box.
    }
}]);

app.directive('myMap', function() {
   var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
       function initMap(){..};   
       function setMarker(map, position, title, content,link){..};
       function returnMarker(){..};
   }
   return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div id="gmaps"></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: link
    };
});

app.filter('marksersFilter', function () {
        return function (objects, markerObj) {
            if (!objects)
                return [];
            else if (!(markerObj))
                return objects;
            else {
                var result = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                    // do comparision here, if found push object to result array
                            result.push(objects[i]);                        
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    });
```

-- index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<head>...</head>
<body>
   <input type="search" ng-change="searchMarkers()" placeholder="Search your place" ng-model='search'></input>
<p ng-repeat="marker in myMarkers| marksersFilter: search"> {{marker.title}}</p>

<div my-map=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

i hope this answered your question of how to "Search item in an array of another JS file using Angular)

Comment: Thank you very much but I have a problem. Indeed, I don't know how to define the app.controller in the app.js : ``ReferenceError: app is not defined`` and the directive (and the map) is not working anymore. Thank you.
Furthermore, do I have to add something more to show the list of the results of the comparaison in the index.html such as ``<p ng-repeat="marker in myMarkers| filter: search> {{marker.title}}</p>``

Comment: I updated my answer to solve the `app is not defined` and included directive

Comment: I saw. Thanks. Sorry to bother you again but now I got this : ``Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`` Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: I included the filter, pls try.

Comment: ``Argument 'myController' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ng/areq?p0=myController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined`` I have this now.
But even if the controller is not working, I don't understand why I cannot still have the map (which is in the directive).

Comment: I still got the same error + `` Module 'myApp' is not available!`. Thank you for your time. Maybe you prefer discuss with the chat ?

Comment: I thought I can but I don't have enought "reputation"

Comment: I instantiated the `app` in `app.js` and get it in `markers.js`... pls try

Comment: Great ! Thanks, I can see the markers now with the map. But the research isn't working.

This is my code 

index.html
``<input type="search" ng-change="searchMarkers(myMarkers,search)" placeholder="Search your place" ng-model='search'></input>
        <p ng-repeat="marker in myMarkers| marksersFilter: search"> {{marker.title}}</p>``

  app.js
``$scope.searchMarkers = function(arr,obj){
// loop through your markers array and compare with the entered value in text box.

            for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == obj) return true;
            }``

Comment: and then in the filter : ``for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                    // do comparision here, if found push object to result array
                    if (markerObj[i] == objects) {
                        
                        result.push(objects[i]); 
                        }                       
                }``

Comment: You don't need searchmarkers any more. Just use the filter. Your if condition isn't right, you compare the object to the array. Check on object fields (method1... Or whatever)

Comment: Pls don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you out

Comment: What do you mean ? Why don't I nedd searchmarkers any more ? And you mean a condition like ``if (markerObj[i] == objects.title)``

Comment: U can do something like: if(markerObj.method1 === objects[i].method1) , i am on the train, so excuse my formatting

Comment: don't worry thx. Do i have to define objects like an array or a list because I have ``Cannot read property 'length' of undefined``twice

Comment: Don't need the filter actually : ``input placeholder="Search a place" ng-model="search">
                <div ng-show="search.length">
                <p ng-repeat="marker in markers | filter: search"> 
                    {{marker.title}} </p></div>`` works fine ! Thanks